# strange log entry related to webcoreglue in android

Tags: android, logcat, ddms

Since 2 days , I get the following error when I run my app on the device,
however it runs fine on the emulator
can anyone help me in solving this error?

```
 E  3762    webcoreglue the real object has been deleted

 E  3762    webcoreglue the real object has been deleted

 E  3762    webcoreglue the real object has been deleted

 E  3762    webcoreglue the real object has been deleted
```

it occurs when I am logging in to facebook login webview through my app.

the login dialog appears for a tenth of a second and then disappears

any suggestions?
thanks ..

Answer (score 5):

In my case the webcoreglue "the real object has been deleted" was caused by a missing "webView.destroy();". After calling the activity multiple times i got the error message.

```
@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.help);

   String fileName = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("filename");
   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
   webView.loadUrl(fileName); //file:///...html
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   webView.destroy(); //<-- !!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally related to orientation change (also activity changes). You can generally get around this by adding the following to your manifest for your main activity:

```
android:configChanges=”keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation”
```